# Integrate flask with legacy Database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new with flask, I am trying to create model classes from existing database tables ,in `Django` to achieve that we can use `python manage.py inspectdb` it will create a model classes.
Is there any slimier option in `flask` ?
I searched it and found some options like `SQLAlchemy's` `autoload`, it does not creates models classes on the fly. 
Please suggest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flask is micro [what-does-micro-mean](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/foreword/#what-does-micro-mean)

> The “micro” in microframework means Flask aims to keep the core simple but extensible. Flask won’t make many decisions for you, such as what database to use

so you should understand many options that django has in box not in flask, for many solution you need to find [extension](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensions/#extensions), which is better for your project. And if you whant to use `SQLAlchemy` you can try [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen)
for details:

```
sqlacodegen --help
```